# Group permissions required for few directories

Tags: clearcase, configuration-management

I received one request from one of our client regarding "group permission change for listed folders" from “`abc`” vob as they are not able to change permission due to mastership issue for those folders (Because, mastership lies at our end).

I got request to change the group permissions for our vob's 10 directories. So that they can access and do some analysis through some tools.
But as per our admins, VOB group permissions remains to one group only and they cannot change it.
But our Client is keep on pinging me. As per my R&D, I found "`protectvob`" command. Does the below command works?

```
cleartool protectvob –add_group "groupname" /path_of_the_vob/abc_vob/directory1
```

Please could you check and send me the steps to change group permission for only 10 directories of `abc` vob?

Answer (score 0):

`protectvob` will allow you to add secondary groups to the Vob.
But it won't change the protection on any element within that Vob.
See the examples of [`cleartool protectvob` man page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_protectvob.htm).

To change a group on a collection of files, you can use **[`cleartool protect`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_protect.htm)** (once you have added that group to the secondary groups of your vob, so `protectvob` is still needed):

```
 cleartool find . -nrec -exec "cleartool protect -chgrp \"My Group\" \"%CLEARCASE_PN%\""
```

(adapt the `cleartool find` to list only what you need)